# RSelenium and R-Exporting DIV into table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I would like to extract a **DIV** from a website, in a table, despite it is not actually coded as a table.

I can easily find the correct **DIV** and extract it, but I am struggling to extract train prices keeping the same structure of the website [1° class, 2° class, and Base, Economy, Super Economy].

Here's is the [data source](https://www.lefrecce.it/B2CWeb/search.do?parameter=searchOutputViewer&cFID=YKbm65KPsfJA).

Below the table I'd like to export:

[image]

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: A possile solution could be to download all table and to use the text rules to extract the correct format.

Comment: It is exactly what i did. 
Thanks